# Need help to find a regular expression for name and last name validation

Tags: regex, validation

I tried to find someone with the same problem, but I didn't find anything.

I need two separate regular expressions, one for names, and one for last names.

Here the rules for names:

- A name can't start with spaces, numbers or any other symbol.
- A name must be long at least 3 characters, for a maximum of 15 characters.
- No symbols allowed.

Some allowed name examples:

Malcolm Walter Bob

giovanni francesco

Steven

Here last names rules:

- A last name can't start with spaces, numbers or any other symbol.
- A last name must be long at least 3 characters, for a maximum of 15 characters.
- A last name can contains apostrophes, dots and dash.

Some allowed last names examples:

D'addario

berners Lee

berners lee

O'Riley.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Obligatory link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

First name:

```
[a-zA-Z.\-']+
```

Last name:

```
[a-zA-Z.\-' ]{3,15}
```

Combined:

```
[a-zA-Z.\-' ]+ [a-zA-Z.\-']{3,15}
```

Keep in mind that your restriction on last names is very strict - you'll rule out many Asian last names like Li or Wu.

Also, I'm not sure, if you wanted to make the last name optional. If so:

```
[a-zA-Z.\-' ]+ (?:[a-zA-Z.\-']{3,15})?
```

Comment: Oh, didn't tought at Asians last names, youre right! Thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

For names [A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2,14}[^ ]

- **[A-Z]{1}**

1 capital A-Z char.

- **[a-z]{2,14}**

2 to 14 a-z

- **[^ ]**

without spaces

---

For last names [A-Za-z/.-/']{3,15}[^ ]

- **[A-Za-z/.-/']{3,15}**

A-Z or a-z . - ' 3 to 15 long

- **[^ ]**

without spaces

---

Try Here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/